# webpage shows just part of ssh execution results

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

hello i am running several ssh commands in one session, the two commands execute and show results on command prompt( first results are shown then after a minute second results are show), but on my web page it shows just half of the results, that is the result of the first execution an d just a small fraction of the second execution. so please can someone help me?
here are my codes:

```
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("dis inter eth-trunk 3\n"); // note the "\n"
$results= $ssh->read('username@username:~$');

echo $results;
$myfile = fopen("data1.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $results;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("dis inter eth-trunk 12\n"); // note the "\n"

$result= $ssh->read('username:~$');
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice your prompt is different in each of your `$ssh->read()` calls.

I almost wonder if, for your second attempt, it's timing out before the full output is sent,  at which point,  doing `$ssh->setTimeout(30)` might work.